# Baseline predictors

Tags: математика

Привет всем!

У меня вопрос по методу прогнозирования baseline predictors.

У меня есть сумма оценок для каждого пользователей и сумма оценок для каждого элемента.
Теперь я пытаюсь спрогнозировать как определенный пользователь оценит какой либо элемент. Делаю я это так

`raw_average + bias (пользователя) + bias (элемента)`

Каждый `bias` я нахожу, как

`(сумма всех оценок конкретным пользователем (или сумма всех оценок конкретного элемента) / кол-во оценок) - raw_average`

Но есть пользователи, которые могут не оценить ни 1го элемента. Тоже самое касается элемента (Какой нибудь элемент может никто не оценить).

И что тогда? Тогда `кол-во элементов` == 0 в bias ..., И нужно я делить на ноль...

Comment: @boomeer, Скорее всего вам быстрее помогут на [Математике](http://math.hashcode.ru/).